# ngClass mixed with strings and objects

Tags: angular

I need to add a couple of classes to an element. In my case the problem is that one class is a simple string, `'start-' + i` and the other is conditional `{'is-active': i <= totalStars}`

I would say that this sounds easy, but when I try it, it looks like the opposite

```
<ul>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let star of stars; let i = index">
        <li [ngClass]="['star-' + i, {'is-active': i <= totalStars}]">....</li>
    </ng-container>
</ul>
```

The above code doesn't work (no classes set). I tried variations

```
[ngClass]="{'start-' + i: true, 'is-active': i <= totalStars}"
[ngClass]="'start-' + i" [ngClass]="{'is-active': i <= totalStars}"
[ngClass="['start-' + i, amount >= i ? 'is-active' : '']"
```

Without success. Any suggestions how to do this?

Best solution so far is to use a function to construct the classes

```
[ngClass]="getClasses(i)"
```

Comment: What is `totalStars`?

Comment: Why are you calling function from template : `getClasses(i)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add string `start-{{i}}` as separate class and use conditional classes in `[ngClass]`.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let start of starts; let i = index" class="start-{{i}}" [ngClass]="{'is-active': i < totalStars}">...</li>
</ul>
```

And you dont have to use `ng-container` you can directly apply `*ngFor` on `li`.

Comment: Thanks, this is it. I used the `ng-container` here to improve the readability only

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
<li [class]=" i <= totalStars ? 'start-' + i + ' is-active' : 'start-' + i ">
        ...
</li>
```

**See [Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bwjwzc?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: This is close, but I always need the `'star-' + i`, that one is not optional, the `is-active` is

Comment: Check the modified answer

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Your solution doesn't scale very well. If at some point classes are added, it might get complex or not work any more